# Enzyme/ReactJS: How to find specific child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to do a enzyme/jest unit test for a component. I need to simulate a change event of a specific child component (as there are two of them).

```
const wrapper = shallow(<CreateAccount />)
wrapper.find({ name: 'username' }).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Username' } })
wrapper.find({ password: 'password' }).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Password' } })
const state = wrapper.instance().state
expect(state).toEqual({ username: 'Username', password: 'Password' })
```

But this is not the correct way to find both Input components...

This is how my render() function of my component looks like:

```
render () {
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={this._onSubmit.bind(this)}>
      <Input
        value={this.state.description}
        onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
        name='username'
        type='text'
        placeholder='Username'
      />
      <Input
        value={this.state.url}
        onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
        name='password'
        type='password'
        placeholder='Password'
      />
      <Button type='submit'>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `find()` returns an array so you have to use `at(index)` or `first()` to access specific element:

http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/at.html
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/first.html

In your case you can also import `Input` component and find them like this:

```
import Input from 'input-component-path'

...
wrapper.find(Input).at(0).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Username' } })
wrapper.find(Input).at(1).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Password' } })
```

Comment: Can't I select the component by a given prop? In this example  there is the name property...

Comment: Yes, you can but still you need to use `at(index)` or `first()` to access element and simulate event